# How to bind a particular GPU to a task

Tags: gpu, slurm

I have two GPUs in my system. I want my task to be executed on GPU 1 (not on GPU 0).

Below are my options. Slurm does not bind my task to GPU 1 despite --gpu-bind option. It starts up my task at GPU 0:

```
#SBATCH --job-name=Genkin_CPU
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --gpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH -e log/slurm_%A_%a.err
#SBATCH -o log/slurm_%A_%a.out
#SBATCH -t "100000"
#SBATCH --array=1-1
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --gpu-bind=map_gpu:1
```

Comment: If they're from 2 different architectures like kepler (K80) or tesla (T4) or volta (V100) then you can specify in the `--gres=gpu:tesla:1` to ensure it selects the correct GPU. If they're the same, then you could start a dummy interactive job on GPU 0 by `salloc .... --gres=gpu:1` followed by submitting your actual job script using sbatch. This way, GPU 0 will be already allocated when you submit your job & GPU 1 will be the only option.

Comment: @akshayk07, the GPUs are exactly the same. And yeah, this is exactly what I am doing currently: schedule a dummy task on GPU 0, schedule a real task on GPU 1, and kill GPU 0 task